# JIRA Rest API - JQL Advanded Search with "order by"

Tags: api, rest, jira

I have implemented a service to find JIRA issues by Rest calls. Before I used the SOAP API, but I read, that this API is still there but will not developed further on.
In my old service I had a JQL advanced search with an "order by" in the query and everything worked fine. Now, in the Rest calls, the "order by" do not work anymore.
Is there no possibility to do that or do I something wrong?
I tried two different versions:

https://www.jirawebsite.de/rest/api/2/search?jql=project='projectname'&update>='2012/07/15%2012:00'&update<='2012/07/25%2012:00'+order+by+key+DESC

https://www.jirawebsite.de/rest/api/2/search?jql=project='projectname'&update>='2012/07/15%2012:00'&update<='2012/07/25%2012:00'%20order%20by%20key%20DESC

Both do not work, which means, I get the issues but in no specific ordering.
On atlassian page I've read, that an filter overwrites the "order by". Does this mean, that it is not possible to order the issues by query or do I have an mistake in my call?
My google- and forum searches do not have any results for me..

Thanks.

Greetings
Carsten

Comment: That should work. The way to get the right URL is to look on the Issue Navigator page for the icon () that is the permlink for a query. That should have the characters all escaped properly, which is probably your problem here.